# How to network between multiple containers of the same image in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose and my configuration file is simply:

```
version: '3.7'
volumes:
  mongodb_data: {}
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.4.3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=super-secure-password
  rocket:
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    image: rocket:dev
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 8.8.8.8
    volumes:
      - .:/var/rocket
    ports:
      - "30301-30309:30300"
```

I start MongoDB with `docker-compose up`, and then in new terminal windows run two Node.js application each with all the source code in `/var/rocket` with:

```
# 1st Node.js application
docker-compose run --service-ports rocket
```

```
# 2nd Node.js application
docker-compose run --service-ports rocket
```

The problem is that the 2nd Node.js application service needs to communicate with the 1st Node.js application service on port `30300`. I was able to get this working by referencing the 1st Node.js application by the id of the Docker container:

Connect to 1st Node.js application service on: `tcp://myapp_myapp_run_837785c85abb:30300` from the 2nd Node.js application service.

Obviously this does not work long term as the container id changes every time I `docker-compose up` and `down`. Is there a standard way to do networking when you start multiple of the same container from docker-compose?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the same image multiple times in the same `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongodb: { ... }
  rocket1:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "30301:30300"
  rocket2:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "30302:30300"
```

As described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), the containers can communicate using their respective service names and their "normal" port numbers, like `rocket1:30300`; any `ports:` are ignored for this.  You shouldn't need to manually `docker-compose run` anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could always give specific names to your two Node containers:

```
$ docker-compose run --name rocket1 --service-ports rocket
$ docker-compose run --name rocket2 --service-ports rocket
```

And then use:

```
tcp://rocket1:30300
```

Comment: Yah, I was looking for a cleaner way, without having to manually remember to set the `--name` for both containers each time.

Comment: I at least don't know of any :/

Comment: What about defining two rockets in the `docker-compose.yaml` that are identical just named `rocket1` and `rocket2`

Comment: Yeah that is ofc a possibility if you always keep the count as 2. It would anyways be the better way if you intend to always have an exact amount of the services. That way you could specify it using `container_name: rocket1` and `container_name: rocker2` in the compose file.

Comment: Is there a way to have `docker-compose up` start MongoDB but then drop me into a `bash` terminal in the rocket container? Right now rocket exits with code 0, and I have to run `docker-compose run` after `up`? Note the Dockerfile just has `CMD ["/bin/bash"]`